# Regexp, how to mach exactly

Tags: ruby, regex

Ho to match exactly 6 or 8 or 10 figures numbers?

```
"787876" =~ /^\d{6}$/ -> TRUE
"78787633" =~ /^\d{8}$/ -> TRUE
"7878733226" =~ /^\d{10}$/ -> TRUE
"7878736" =~ /^\d{6}$/ -> FALSE
```

Ho to create one regexp for these cases.
Shorter form of:

```
"787876" =~ /^\d{6}$|^\d{8}$|^\d{10}$/
```

Comment: `string =~ /\A\d+\z/ && [6, 8, 10].include?(string.size)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this regex `^\d{6}(\d{2}){0,2}$`

Comment: Could you explain me this solutin?

Comment: 6 digits, followed by zero, one or two groups of 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

another solution: `/^\d{10}|\d{8}|\d{6}$/`

Answer (score 1):

The shortest form I can think of is this:

```
/^(\d\d){3,5}$/
```

That's 3 to 5 pairs of digits.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with massive data, this one may be a good option, because it doesn't have parentheses to run sub-match and store the sub-results.

```
/^\d{2}{3,5}$/
```

IMHO, there are two principles of writing a regular expression:

1. Keep it intuitive, of course you can leave comments, but the more intuitive, the less chance of making mistake;
2. Try to avoid using parentheses if you don't want to execute sub-match, since the results of sub-matching will be grouped in an array, which costs extra spaces.